# Running Grails (J)Unit Tests in Intellij Idea

Tags: grails, groovy, junit

I am trying to run unit tests in Intellij IDEA in the same way I was doing it in Eclipse. 
This is a Grails project, and I am getting this error when trying to run them as JUnit tests:

```
assertEquals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) in grails.plugins.selenium.GrailsSeleniumTestCase cannot override assertEquals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) in groovy.util.GroovyTestCase; overridden method is static
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Looks like you have a selenium plugin installed, that tries to override assertEquals. Can you show us the test, and does it work from command line?

Comment: If I run grails test-app unit: -echoOut it works great fine, but it takes a lot of time to run a single unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working. Thanks very much @splix, I uninstalled the selenium plugin (which seems to be ignored by STS eclipse).